# How do I install Hyper-V on the Dell X 13 (2015) with Windows 8.1

Tags: hyper-v, dell-xps

I have checked all the hardware requirements from the BIOS and everything supports Hyper-V on mhy Dell xps 13 (2015). The problem is there is no option in add features.

Comment: that was for windows 8, this is about windows 8.1

Comment: There is **no difference** between Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 when it comes to Hyper-V hardware or license requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hyper-V feature is only supported on the 64-bit Pro and Enterprise versions of Windows 8.1.

If you have only the regular version of Windows 8.1, or if you're running a 32-bit version, that would explain why you do not see the feature available.

[This product matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx) from Microsoft's web site lists the feature differences between the various editions of Windows 8/8.1.  Hyper-V is located under the Management category for some strange reason.

Comment: I have the regular windows 8.1

Comment: The regular version of Windows 8.1 does not support Hyper-V.  You will need to upgrade to Pro.

Comment: Thanks. :)
But I have heard that hyper-v is given as  a free feature. Anyways.

Comment: In this case, "free" is a loaded phrase :-)  It is free -- if you paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Hyper‑V on Windows 8.1

1. In Control Panel, tap or click Programs, and then tap or click Programs and Features.
2. Tap or click Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. Select Hyper‑V, tap or click OK, and then tap or click Close.
4. Shut down your PC, and then restart it.

Depending on your manufacturer, you might have to pause a few seconds with the PC off before restarting for the required changes to take effect. If you're using a laptop, you might have to remove the battery before restarting.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/hyper-v-run-virtual-machines
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

If you Opt-ed for the Windows 7 Downgrade (or didn't spring for the Windows 8.1 Pro version), there is no option and you will be unable to use Hyper-V on your system.

P.S. Excellent choice on a system. I'd be interested in getting your opinion on it but that's Off-Topic.